# Visual Studio 2019 adding app.config to library projects

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

For some reason, I think after updating VS 2019 and opening my solution, VS added app.config files to all of my projects in the solution. These files contain nothing but "dependentAssembly" sections.

I'm not sure why these files have been added, especially without asking. I'm also not sure what they are doing. I didn't think that library projects used app.config files.

Any ideas as to what they are being used for?